# Left and Right alignment in pyplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

In the legend of my plot, I want to display the (best) values of the functions as well, next to the 'normal' legend.

My current try:

[image]

Which I have coded like this:

```
for j, pol in enumerate(pols):
        val = vidics[1][pol]
        axis[1,i].axhline(val, label=f'{pol_label[j]}: {val:.1f}', color='r', linestyle = st[j])
    
sns.lineplot(x= 'variable',y='value',data=pd.DataFrame(r_FI_3).melt(), label = f'FI: {score_FI_3:.1f}', ax=axis[1,i])
sns.lineplot(x= 'variable',y='value',data=pd.DataFrame(r_PO_3).melt(), label = f'PO: {score_PO_3:.1f}', ax=axis[1,i])
```

The for loop creates the horizontal lines.
The sns lines create the blue and orange lines.

What I would like to have is that the scores (the values in the legend) are right aligned.
Doing this manually by adding spaces in the fstrings is not feasible as I've many of these small plots filled in a loop. I tried adding blanks/fills in the fstring, e.g. the following label for the second sns line:

```
label = f'{"PO": < 10}: {score_PO_3:.1f}'
```

Which adds blanks untill the string got a length of 10 (I think?). I thought If I would do that for all the strings, the right would align out but as not all the characters in the string have the same width this also does not work and looks ugly.

Any ideas?

Furthermore, a the larger code, for reference:

```
pols = ['optimal', 'preventive', 'corrective']
pol_label = ['VIoptm', 'VIprev', 'VIcorr']
vidics = [vi2, vi3, vi4]

labels = ['4', '5', '6', '7']

dics2_PO = [s4_PO_2, s5_PO_2, s6_PO_2, s7_PO_2]
dics2_FI = [s4_FI_2, s5_FI_2, s6_FI_2, s7_FI_2]

dics3_PO = [s4_PO_3, s5_PO_3, s6_PO_3, s7_PO_3]
dics3_FI = [s4_FI_3, s5_FI_3, s6_FI_3, s7_FI_3]

dics4_PO = [s4_PO_4, s5_PO_4, s6_PO_4, s7_PO_4]
dics4_FI = [s4_FI_4, s5_FI_4, s6_FI_4, s7_FI_4]

figlabel = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k','l']]

fig, axis = plt.subplots(3,4, figsize=(17,10))

st = ['-', '-.' , ':']

for i in range(4):
    # 2 comp
    dic2FI = dics2_FI[i]
    dic2PO = dics2_PO[i]
    
    r_FI_2 = dic2FI['ar']
    r_PO_2 = dic2PO['ar']
    
    t_PO_2 = np.array(dic2PO['t']).sum()
    
    best_r_FI = np.array(dic2FI['best_r'])
    best_r_PO = np.array(dic2PO['best_r'])
    
    score_FI_2 = best_r_FI.mean()
    score_PO_2 = best_r_PO.mean()
    
    sd_FI_2 = best_r_FI.std()
    sd_PO_2 = best_r_PO.std()
    
    print(f'2comp, agent {labels[i]} FI : {score_FI_2:.1f} +- {sd_FI_2:.1f} ')
    print(f'2comp, agent {labels[i]} PO : {score_PO_2:.1f} +- {sd_PO_2:.1f} ')
    print(f'2comp, agent {labels[i]} PO , time: {t_PO_2:.0f}')
    
    for j, pol in enumerate(pols):
        val = vidics[0][pol]
        axis[0,i].axhline(val, label=f'{pol_label[j]}: {val:.1f}', color='r', linestyle = st[j])
    
    sns.lineplot(x= 'variable',y='value',data=pd.DataFrame(r_FI_2).melt(), label = f'FI: {score_FI_2:.1f}', ax=axis[0,i])
    sns.lineplot(x= 'variable',y='value',data=pd.DataFrame(r_PO_2).melt(), label = f'PO: {score_PO_2:.1f}', ax=axis[0,i])
    
    axis[0,i].set_ylim((-30,-8))
    axis[0,i].legend(loc='lower right')
    axis[0,i].set_xlabel('Training Iterations')
    axis[0,i].set_xticks([4,9])
    axis[0,i].set_xticklabels(['50k', '100k'])
    axis[0,i].set_title(f'{figlabel[0][i]}) 2 comp, agent {labels[i]}')
    if i==0:
        axis[0,i].set_ylabel('Average Reward')
    else:
        axis[0,i].set_ylabel('')
            

    
    # 3 comp
    dic3FI = dics3_FI[i]
    dic3PO = dics3_PO[i]
    
    r_FI_3 = dic3FI['ar']
    r_PO_3 = dic3PO['ar']
    
    t_PO_3 = np.array(dic3PO['t']).sum()
    
    best_r_FI = np.array(dic3FI['best_r'])
    best_r_PO = np.array(dic3PO['best_r'])
    
    score_FI_3 = best_r_FI.mean()
    score_PO_3 = best_r_PO.mean()
    
    sd_FI_3 = best_r_FI.std()
    sd_PO_3 = best_r_PO.std()
    
    print(f'3comp, agent {labels[i]} FI : {score_FI_3:.1f} +- {sd_FI_3:.1f} ')
    print(f'3comp, agent {labels[i]} PO : {score_PO_3:.1f} +- {sd_PO_3:.1f} ')
    print(f'3comp, agent {labels[i]} PO , time: {t_PO_3:.0f}')
    
    for j, pol in enumerate(pols):
        val = vidics[1][pol]
        axis[1,i].axhline(val, label=f'{pol_label[j]}: {val:.1f}', color='r', linestyle = st[j])
    
    sns.lineplot(x= 'variable',y='value',data=pd.DataFrame(r_FI_3).melt(), label = f'FI: {score_FI_3:.1f}', ax=axis[1,i])
    sns.lineplot(x= 'variable',y='value',data=pd.DataFrame(r_PO_3).melt(), label = f'PO: {score_PO_3:.1f}', ax=axis[1,i])
    
    axis[1,i].set_ylim((-60,-15))
    axis[1,i].legend(loc='lower right')
    axis[1,i].set_xlabel('Training Iterations')
    axis[1,i].set_xticks([4,9])
    axis[1,i].set_xticklabels(['100k', '200k'])
    axis[1,i].set_title(f'{figlabel[1][i]}) 3 comp, agent {labels[i]}')
    if i==0:
        axis[1,i].set_ylabel('Average Reward')
    else:
        axis[1,i].set_ylabel('')
   
    
    
     # 4 comp
    dic4FI = dics4_FI[i]
    dic4PO = dics4_PO[i]
    
    r_FI_4 = dic4FI['ar']
    r_PO_4 = dic4PO['ar']
    
    t_PO_4 = np.array(dic4PO['t']).sum()
    
    best_r_FI = np.array(dic4FI['best_r'])
    best_r_PO = np.array(dic4PO['best_r'])
    
    score_FI_4 = best_r_FI.mean()
    score_PO_4 = best_r_PO.mean()
    
    sd_FI_4 = best_r_FI.std()
    sd_PO_4 = best_r_PO.std()
    
    print(f'4comp, agent {labels[i]} FI : {score_FI_4:.1f} +- {sd_FI_4:.1f} ')
    print(f'4comp, agent {labels[i]} PO : {score_PO_4:.1f} +- {sd_PO_4:.1f} ')
    print(f'4comp, agent {labels[i]} PO , time: {t_PO_4:.0f}')
    
    for j, pol in enumerate(pols):
        val = vidics[2][pol]
        axis[2,i].axhline(val, label=f'{pol_label[j]}: {val:.1f}', color='r', linestyle = st[j])
    
    sns.lineplot(x= 'variable',y='value',data=pd.DataFrame(r_FI_4).melt(), label = f'FI: {score_FI_4:.1f}', ax=axis[2,i])
    sns.lineplot(x= 'variable',y='value',data=pd.DataFrame(r_PO_4).melt(), label = f'PO: {score_PO_4:.1f}', ax=axis[2,i])
    
    axis[2,i].set_ylim((-70,-20))
    axis[2,i].legend(loc='lower right')
    axis[2,i].set_xlabel('Training Iterations')
    axis[2,i].set_xticks([4,9])
    axis[2,i].set_xticklabels(['200k', '400k'])
    axis[2,i].set_title(f'{figlabel[2][i]}) 4 comp, agent {labels[i]}')
    if i==0:
        axis[2,i].set_ylabel('Average Reward')
    else:
        axis[2,i].set_ylabel('')
    
   
    
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Which creates the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at where you assign the label value:

```
label=f'{pol_label[j]}: {val:.1f}'
```

In this format all is left aligned. It's comparabale with e.g.:

```
print('{:<2}: {:<8}'.format(*['label','value']))
```

which means something like, 'left align everything, but let the first word have an available space of 2 (counting from left), and the second a space of 8'

To fix I would try to keep the first word left-aligned but the second right-aligned, given an appropriate available space. In the above line, simply change the second sign, and possibly the space:

```
 print('{:<2}: {:>8}'.format(*['label','value']))
```

to achieve (output):

```
label:      value
```

(Label is left aligned, value is right-aligned)

[reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: Note that this will only work with a monospaced font, which doesn't look as nice as a standard proportional font.